# Using URL Query Parameters on POST

Tags: rest, http

My team needs to build an API for uploading documents e.g. PDFs.  One of my goals is to make this as painless as possible for the callers.  I believe a POST call with the binary content provided as a stream is the most straightforward.  A team-member noted that there was a need to provide metadata along with this document.  His assumption that this would require a multi-part-mime request.  In my opinion, this adds a significant amount of complexity for the users of the service.

I suggested the idea setting the metadata in the 'query string' of the URL.  This allows for the metadata and a simple stream solution for the document.  We both are confident that this should work from a technical perspective, but he felt this was non-standard or potentially not RESTful.

It seems like a pretty straightforward solution to me but I indeed cannot find any clear answer on whether this is problematic.  I found a few discussions that seem to be about this but the answers all seem to veer off into "mixing GET and POST" which I don't follow at all.  Unless I'm missing something, this has nothing to do with GET, just POST and how the URL for that POST is structured.  It seems like there's an idea that query parameters are only supported by GET but I don't believe that's the case.

Can anyone provide an authoritative reference on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "problematic". There's probably nothing wrong with it from an usability perspective. Remember, REST is an architectural **style**, and authoritative references on styles can be as subjective as the styles themselves. You can find an authoritative reference on the transport protocol you are using, HTTP, but when is a deviation from the protocol problematic, and when it's merely against purism? Read the RFCs 7230 and 7231 and try to figure it out.

In other words, I'm saying that if you're after an authoritative source to settle an argument with your colleagues, I don't think you're going to find it.

If you just want to clarify it, from the REST perspective, URIs are atomic identifiers of resources. Query parameters are part of the identifier, but since they are atomic, their semantics is irrelevant. This means that any discussion about whether an URI is RESTful or not is pointless. As long as an URI points to one and only one resource and it's not obtained from out-of-band information, it's RESTful, regardless of its contents. Sure, you should try to have meaningful and simple URIs, that are easy to understand, but this is a general best-pratice on HTTP, not a REST constraint.

The real problem in your case is that the semantics of the POST method is to submit the payload to be processed by the resource identified by the URI, under predefined rules. The URI you are using in the POST does not identify the file you are uploading, but the resource responsible for the uploading. If you are including metadata for processing in the URI, you are effectively saying that every PDF file is uploaded with a different uploader resource. There's nothing inherently wrong with that from a REST perspective, but it's strange from an HTTP and usability perspective. I'd expect the same resource to be used for everyone, and additional data to be present in the payload. In this point I think your colleague is correct, that you should use a multi-part-mime request, or a media-type format that allows you to pack the pdf file and the metadata together in the payload.

However, if your metadata doesn't change after the PDF file is uploaded -- or in other words, if your URI doesn't change -- it's perfectly fine to do that with a PUT method. Differently from the POST method, PUT does not submit the payload to be processed by the resource identified by the URI, but asks the server to replace the resource at the URI with the one enclosed in the payload. In this case the URI really identifies the PDF file, so it's ok, as long as that's not going to change.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to provide such a well written and thought out response.  I think I am following you up until this point "you are effectively saying that every PDF file is uploaded with a different uploader resource".  I don't think I understant who you are using the term 'uploader resource' in this context.

Comment: To further explain the scenario, it's crucial to correctness that the URI in this case be created by the API so PUT is really out of the question.  The metadata here is essentially for tagging documents so they can be found in searches.  They have have no effect on the URI or the content of the resource.

Comment: URIs are atomic. Querystrings are not "parameters", they are part of the URI. POST method submits the payload to the target resource, so every PDF file is handled by a different URI, so you have either different resources doing the same thing, or countless different URIs referring to the same resource.

Comment: If PUT is out of the question, then I agree with your colleague. You should go with POST and a media-type that allows submitting the file and the metadata in the payload.

Comment: OK, I follow you now.  I don't doubt that you are correct here but I have some doubts about the practicality of this.  One of the problems that I have here is that query strings are commonly referred to as "parameters" https://www.google.com/search?q=query+string+parameters.  Interestingly enough, the URI that my search constructed contained a number of other elements of the form: "&oq=query+string+parameters&aqs=chrome..6i57.62j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8" which appear to have no impact on the results returned from the search.

Comment: Further confusing the matter (for me) is that "query parameters" (as they are sometimes called) https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String) "...are contained in the query string or posted form data."

Comment: You're talking of implementation semantics. In REST, and URI is an atomic identifier. If a particular implementation decides to deliver querystring parameters as equivalent to post form data, you have to workaround that to threat the URI as atomic, not assuming the implementation is correct.

Comment: If your question is about practicality, then I don't understand the discussion. Practicality is subjective and depends a lot on what you already have. I would prefer to be consistent with a broken implementation than to fix only a part for purism.

Comment: We only have one other RESTful service at this time.  It's a GET for documents.  The URIs for these are retrievable only from searches at this time (this new service would provide a generated URI.)  My question about practicality is what actual real world issue would be caused by doing this?  Is there something aside from purism?  HTTP is not strictly compliant to REST paradigm per Fielding's thesis.  So is this a REST issue or a HTTP issue or simply a conventions issue?

Comment: So I was searching through [RESTFul Web Services] (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do) for something that was relevant and the author's seem to really dislike query strings, so there's that.  But this caught my eye on page page 219: "A POST is an attempt to create a new resource from an existing one ... Or the existing resource may be a special "factory" resource whose only purpose is to generate existing resources."  I was thinking of this as the latter but perhaps it could be thought of as part of the resource that is searchable via the provided query string key-value pairs.

Comment: Also for full disclosure, I hate multi-part-mime.  I was recently trying to use a REST API that made extensive use of it and it was frankly a crap interface.  It was really dependent on assumptions around how the payload was structured by a specific client and you would basically have to snoop the traffic from that client to 'discover' the API.  Might just be me but it left a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: I sense you have lost interest in this discussion but after mentioning Fielding, I decided to go refresh my memory of what in HTTP wasn't RESTful.  Under 6.3.4.5, it contains a description of why multi-part-mime is not RESTful. https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_3

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place for prolonged discussions like that.